# How do we mock HealthCheckService and CheckHealthAsync given it's an abstract class

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking

I Implemented Heartbeat service similarly like below example.
[How to add Health Checks to Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72115090/how-to-add-health-checks-to-swagger)

I have requirement add as endpoint to swagger without healthcheck UI and its own endpoint .

I need help to mock the  HealthCheckService for my unit testing.